# Copying a file from container to locally by using volume mounts

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Trying to copy files from the container to the local first

So, I have a custom Dockerfile, RUN mkdir /test1 && touch /test1/1.txt and then I build my image and I have created an empty folder in local path /root/test1

and docker run -d --name container1 -v /root/test1:/test1 Image:1

I tried to copy files from containers to the local folder, and I wanted to use it later on. but it is taking my local folder as a preceding and making my container empty.

Could you please someone help me here?

For example, I have built my own custom Jenkins file, for the first time while launching it I need to copy all the configurations and changes locally from the container, and later if wanted to delete my container and launch it again don't need to configure from the scratch.

Thanks,

Comment: Try calling the folder you are mounting something different? e.g. `-v /root/test1:/test2`

Answer (score 1):

The relatively new `--mount` flag replaces the `-v/--volume` mount. It's easier to understand (syntactically) and is also more verbose (see https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

You can mount and copy with:

```
docker run -i \
           --rm \
           --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/root/test1,target=/test1 \
            /bin/bash << COMMANDS
                cp <files> /test1
            COMMANDS
```

where you need to adjust the `cp` command to your needs. I'm not sure if you need the `"$(pwd)"` part.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top, without testing to confirm, i think it is

```
docker cp container1:/path/on/container/filename /path/on/hostmachine/
```

EDIT: Yes that should work. Also "container1" is used here because that was the container's name provided in the example

In general it works like this

container to host

```
docker cp containername:/containerpath/ /hostpath/
```

host to container

```
docker cp /hostpath/ containername:/containerpath/
```

Comment: This method works for copying files, but it's not using a volume mount right? If you mount it, the local directory will always stay synced with the Docker directory.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the question, i thought he just wanted to copy a file from the container to the host

I read it again and it seems like he is saying his bind mount is not working. A bind mount should essentially act as a "shared folder" between host and container

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes I don't want to copy the files from the container to local, but when we mounting the local directory to the container it should copy the files right (kind of taking backup of the files from the container to local,) when we delete the container and launching new container we don't loose any latest data.